# Centered toobar buttons on OnsenUI BottomToolbar

Tags: onsen-ui

I try to make toolbar buttons centered by this code but it is not working.

```
<ons-bottom-toolbar fixed-style>
    <div class="center">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="">كارگاه 1</ons-toolbar-button>
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="">كارگاه 2</ons-toolbar-button>
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="">كارگاه 3</ons-toolbar-button>
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="">نمايشگاه</ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
</ons-bottom-toolbar>
```

Is there any thing that I can do?

Comment: How do you mean by "centered"? The buttons will be placed in the center with that code: http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/gbwZym

Comment: @AndreasArgelius When using `ons-toolbar` you are right but when using `ons-bottom-toolbar` it won't become centered horitoztaly http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNwyBM

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and got a workaround,

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-bottom-toolbar>
    <div class="tab-bar">
      <label ng-click="" class="tab-bar__item">
        <input type="radio" name="tab-bar-b">
             <button class="tab-bar__button">
               كارگاه 1
             </button>
      </label>
      <label ng-click="" class="tab-bar__item">
        <input type="radio" name="tab-bar-b">
             <button class="tab-bar__button">
               كارگاه 2
             </button>
      </label>
      <label ng-click="" class="tab-bar__item">
        <input type="radio" name="tab-bar-b">
             <button class="tab-bar__button">
               كارگاه 3
             </button>
      </label>
      <label ng-click="" class="tab-bar__item">
        <input type="radio" name="tab-bar-b">
             <button class="tab-bar__button">
               نمايشگاه4
             </button>
      </label>
      <!--
      <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="">كارگاه 1</ons-toolbar-button>
      <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="">كارگاه 2</ons-toolbar-button>
      <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="">كارگاه 3</ons-toolbar-button>
      <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="">نمايشگاه</ons-toolbar-button> -->
    </div>
  </ons-bottom-toolbar>
</ons-page>
```

Sadly, I also need the same thing without a workaround.
check out the working [codepen](http://codepen.io/ranjith_varadan/pen/dPpEWO)

Comment: Thanks, let us wait to see what @andreas will answer (he has a good parctice in onsen)